# Performance issues when Web API calling from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api2

I have a [asp.net-web-api2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api2) project. I am trying to call an API from SQL Server.

I am concerned about pros and cons on performance when calling Web API from a SQL Server stored procedure; I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497364/potential-performance-issues-when-calling-web-service-from-sql-clr), but it talks about SQL CLR.

Is it costly to the database? Any other possible ways to achieve the same?

Help me with any suggestions or related articles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to call out to a web service from *within* a SQL Server stored procedure, then indeed, using the SQL CLR and writing your SQL CLR stored procedure in C# is definitely a good way to go. Calling an external web service from T-SQL is anything but easy or efficient....

Comment: Calling web services directly from a database is a bad pattern. What are you actually trying to do? You're better off having middleware that calls the web srevice and pushes data into the database

Answer (score 1):

SQL CLR is supposed to be used to create small functions rather than called out to integrate to other systems. As the answer in the other question states this is not a good idea.  Why not do this in some sort application layer?  What is the driver for doing this in the DB?  Is there a lot of Data, if so should this be an ETL job?  Play to the strengths of each layer of the application.  A application service lay would be a great place to consume the web API do any data manipulation and the send this to the DB.  To be honest I think the other [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497364/potential-performance-issues-when-calling-web-service-from-sql-clr) answers this much better.